# (Swift) How to remove characters more than once using IndexOf

Tags: java, ios, swift

I'm making an iOS app that parses `JSON` data from a google spreadsheet. One of the issues with Google JSON data is that it includes unnecessary data that has to be removed. I'm new to iOS programming.

```
/*O_o*/google.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"0.6","reqId":"0","status":"ok","sig":"1400846503","table":{JSON DATA I NEED}});
```

I have done this in JAVA on Android using this code

```
int start = result.indexOf("{", result.indexOf("{") + 1);
int end = result.lastIndexOf("}");
String jsonResponse = result.substring(start, end);
```

My swift code

```
            var something = "My google JSON Data"
            let Start = String(something).characters.indexOf("{")!;
            let substring1: String = something.substringFromIndex(Start);

            something = substring1;

        let End = String(something).characters.indexOf(")")!.distanceTo(something.endIndex);
        let index3 = something.endIndex.advancedBy(-End);
        let substring4: String = something.substringToIndex(index3)
```

What I'm asking is how do I get the index of the 2nd "{"

Comment: Why not use NSJsonSerializer to convert the JSON into objects and then access it that way. Parsing the text yourself is a bad idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `NSJsonSerializer`, but if you want to do it your way:

```
extension String {
    func indexOf(target: String) -> Int {
        if let range = self.rangeOfString(target) {
            return self.startIndex.distanceTo(range.startIndex)
        } else {
            return -1
        }
    }
    func indexOf(target: String, startIndex: Int) -> Int {
        let startRange = self.startIndex.advancedBy(startIndex)
        if let range = self.rangeOfString(target, options: .LiteralSearch, range: startRange..<self.endIndex) {
            return self.startIndex.distanceTo(range.startIndex)
        } else {
            return -1
        }
    }
}

let end = myString.indexOf("{", startIndex: myString.indexOf("{") + 1)
```

Comment: I think I messed something up got a few errors

'distance' is unavailable call the 'distanceTo(End)' method on the Index
'advance' is unavailable call the 'advanceBy(n)' method on the Index
'Init (start:end)' is deprecated. Use the '..<' operator